# TTF glyph to OBJ

Tags: mesh, fonts

I'm looking for a method to convert a TTF glyph into a triangle mesh.

I've tried making my own font constructing my own indices and vertices but it didn't go well:

[image: bad results]

```
-- This is the A letter
setXYZWHL(0,0,0,3,5,0)
rect(0,0,0,1,4)
rect(2,0,0,1,4)
rect(1,2,0,1,1)
rect(1,4,0,1,1)
triangle(0,4,0, 1,4,0, 1,5,0)
triangle(3,4,0, 2,4,0, 2,5,0)
triangle(1,4,0, 1.5,4,0, 1,3.5,0)
triangle(2,4,0, 1.5,4,0, 2,3.5,0)
```

So I'm looking to convert free TTF fonts made by professionals into my own format instead.

Comment: Hi @MarkWeston, and welcome to GameDev.StackExchange. We don't handle exclusive software/tool recommendation questions on this particular exchange (though there is a Software Recommendations SE if you'd like to try there), so I've edited your question to ask for a method to solve this problem. (Methods can still include software if there are existing programs, but they can also suggest how to fix your own vertex & index generation approach). To ensure you get answers that will be useful to you, can you explain in more detail what "didn't go well" when you tried to do this yourself?

Comment: @Naith Absolutely correct.

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you for your correction. As for "didn't go well", I simply meant that it doesn't look good.